E-commerce for logged-in users
I'm working on designing a small B2B e-commerce platform. I'm having trouble with the architectural aspect and was hoping someone with experience in e-commerce could provide some guidance. - The application is being built as a .NET Core MVC.
I understand that having a database with a "Cart" table and link current cart with the logged-in user is preferable. However, do I always need to query the database to check, for example, how many products are in the shopping cart? For instance, if I add x number of products to the cart and then navigate to another page.
Should I use session/local storage or perhaps cookies to avoid querying the database every time? Anyone working with e-commerce who can help me out here?"
